# How to handle exception control in Node,js?

Tags: node.js, exception, control-flow

With the following code:

```
async function demo(){
   const ret1, ret2, ret3;
   try {
     ret1 = await task1();
   } catch (e) {
      // ...
   }

   if(!ret1.success) {
     return ret1.message;
   }

   try {
      ret2 = await task2();
   } catch (e) {
      // ...
   }

   if(!ret2.success) {
      // retry or rollback task1;
      return;
   }

   try {
      ret3 = await task3();
   } catch (e) {
      // ...
   } 

   if(!ret3.success) {
      // retry or rollback task1
      return;
   }

   return ret3;

}
```

task2 depends on task1, task3 depends on task2. Further more, task1 will insert data in db, so if task2 or task3 failed, it should retry or rollback task1. Any better solution for managing  the tasks? In fact, there will be more than 3 tasks.

Comment: you are talking about database transactions which database are you using and which liobrary to handle

Comment: it's not about database transaction, task2 and task3 are RPC call. Only task1 is database operation. The key point is how to handle multiple tasks gracefullly

Comment: if task2 ot task3 failed it should rollback the task1 right then its called the transactions.the database operation should be reverted right?

Answer (score 0):

The perfect way is a little subjective but I think this one is better.
There are definitely ways of doing it for example if you are using promise then format hence the below should work

```
const demo = () => {
  return task1()
    .then(() => task2())
    .then(() => task3())
    .then(() => task4())
    .then(() => task5())
    .then(() => {
      throw new Error("Testing Error");//Line 8
    })
}

demo()
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    // output
    // Error: Testing Error at task1.then.then.then.then.then index.js:8:13)
  });
```

When using async await format below should work

```
const demo = async () => {
  await task1()
  await task2()
  await task3()
  await task4()
  await task5()
  throw new Error("Testing Error");//Line 7
}

demo()
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    // output
    // Error: Testing Error at demo (index.js:7:9)
  });
```